# \circ with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, circles, latin-modern

I'm using `unicode-math` like so in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
```

Compiling with XeLaTeX, for `$g \circ f$`, I get this:

[image]

But this is different as what I get just deleting the two previous lines of code:

[image]

Noticeably, the `\circ` you get without the previous two lines of code is bigger than the one you get with them.

I would like to know: is there a way in which I could still use `unicode-math` (with the previous two lines of code) yet getting the `\circ` I would get without them?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\[
g \circ f
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without `unicode-math` you get the normal `\circ` symbol in the Computer Modern Symbol font. Apparently, the developers of Latin Modern thought it is too big (and I can agree with them).

Comment: Aside: Do *not* load  the `fontenc` package under XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX).

Comment: @egreg I wanted to keep the original size to use it as in ```\accentset{\circ}{A}``` (using the package ```accents```), to denote the topological interior of a set. Because in this case Computer Modern Symbol's ```\circ``` is just the right size and the one from Latin Modern ends up being too small.

Comment: It doesn't have a significantly different size, but for use as an accent you would normally use `\ocirc` in `unicode-math`.

Comment: You can pick another font’s `\circ` with `\setmathfont[range=\circ, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX TWo Math}`. Or your math font of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the developers of Latin Modern deemed the Computer Modern `\circ` symbol too big (and I don't disagree with them). When you don't load font packages (including `unicode-math`), the default math fonts for XeLaTeX is the standard Computer Modern family. When you load `unicode-math`, the default is Latin Modern Math (be it selected with `\setmathfont` or not).

On the other hand, the fact that `\accentset{\circ}{U}` gives a decent result with the Computer Modern math fonts is more of an accident than a feature: it's just because the symbol is *big* that it seems to sit correctly above a letter.

Let's try some examples based on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

%\usepackage{unicode-math}           % for 2 and 3
%\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}     % for 2
%\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf} % for 3

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
g \circ f \\
\mathring{U}\accentset{\circ}{U}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

### Example 1 – No `unicode-math`

[image]

### Example 2 – With Latin Modern

[image]

### Example 3 – With NewCMMath

[image]

### Comments

As you see, NewCM has taken from Latin Modern.

After looking at the result, my opinion is strongly favoring `\mathring` over `\accentset{\circ}`. But since this is just opinion, let's see how we can do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\CMcirc}{\mathbin}{CMsymbols}{"0E}


\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
g \circ f \\
\mathring{U}\accentset{\CMcirc}{U}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

This defines `\CMcirc` as the Computer Modern `\circ` symbol, so you can use it in `\accentset`.

[image]